# How to increase the air pressure of an air pump?

Tags: pressure, air

How do we increase the air pressure of an air pump or aerator?

In an aquarium shop, I saw a setup like the photo shown below, where in the low pressure air is given as input through a thin inlet pipe, which enters a pipe of higher diameter and is passed to a lower diameter thin pipe outlet with increased pressure.

Can someone explain the physics behind this?

[image]

Comment: This won't increase the pressure.  If you need a higher pressure pump, get a higher pressure pump.

Comment: @Ben51 Nope, the aquarium shop guy showed me in working.

Comment: Don’t buy a bridge from him. If you put low pressure air into something and get a supply of high pressure air out, that something is an *air powered pump*.

Answer (score 1):

Typically these devices are called "pressure intensifiers".

The pressure can be increased by a type of mechanical advantage, like a lever, but using fluid, such as air in "pneumatics", or water or oil in "hydrolics".

More typically in hydrolics/pneumatics the goal is to increase the force.  The force can be increased by having two tubes of different diameters with pistons in each tube moved by the fluid. The larger diameter will produce more force since the pressure is constant ($F = PA$).

Instead of the force, **to increase the pressure connect the two pistons with a rod, so the forces will be the same and the pressures will be different** ($P = F/A$).

Here's a schematic diagram of an intensifier (from [here](https://conceptdraw.com/a2117c3/preview)) that captures the essence of the idea:

[image]

This image depicts the basic idea of a pressure intensifier (and, for reference, if the bar connecting the two pistons were removed it would represent a device for increasing the force).

[Here's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydraulic_intensifier) a relevant wikipedia page for intensifiers.  (Personally I found a search for physics explanations difficult as my search was overwhelmed by devices.  Most of these devices are expensive relative to a pet-store pump, but single stroke devices should be simple and easy to make, like in the schematic.)